# Git clone submodules of submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git project which contains submodules in it.
One of those submodules has its own submodules.

When I am using `git clone --recurse-submodules -j8 git@gitlab.com/example.git` only the first layer of the submodules getting updated and pulls the master branch from the repository.

How can I clone all the master branches in this project?

Tree example:

```
| project A
| Project B
| Project C  
  | Project D
  | Project E
```

All of the projects above are submodules, where A, B and C are cloned as expected and I am getting their master branch, but as for D and E I don't get that.

Comment: I don't understand "*D and E I don't get that*", please clarify. Are projects `D` and `E` submodules of `C`? Are they cloned? fully? partially? not at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

or:

```
git submodule sync --recursive && git submodule update --init --recursive
```